# Using a command for a property within an environment

Tags: environments

I want to use a command within an environment to set an environment's property. I could do this using a parameter, but if I had more properties, parameters might be mixed up.

```
\newenvironment{environment_example} {
  \newcommand\thetitle{Default title.}
  \newcommand\title[1]{\renewcommand\thetitle{#1}}

   This is the \thetitle
}
```

usage:

```
\begin{environment_example}
  \title{A title text}
 \end{environment_example}
```

This is very similar to the figure environment, where the caption is set by a command:

```
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
```

edit: But it does not work. How do I do that?

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: Is this about storing a lot of information,  like using a key-value-interface? It should be `\renewcommand{\title}[1]{...}` with `##1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some reasons because the code does not work:

- `\newcommand{\title}` fails because `\title` is provided by many classes already → use `\renewcommand{\title}`.
- Since it's a redefinition within some other command (an environment actually, the argument parameter is `##1`, not `#1`.

The logical error is using `\thetitle` in the environment start up code -- at this time of calling, `\title` is not yet used at all.

→ `\thetitle` must be placed after `\title` is called. Otherwise use a different interface to the `environment`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\title}[1]{}% Make sure, \title is available

\providecommand{\thetitle}{Default Title}%


\newenvironment{environmentexample}{%
  \renewcommand{\title}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thetitle}{##1}%
  }
  This is the \thetitle.% too early
}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{environmentexample}
  \title{A title text}

  This is the title (now): \thetitle%
 \end{environmentexample}

\end{document}
```

I suggest an optional argument to hold the title, checking whether the opt. argument is empty or not with `\notblank{}` and dropping the `\title` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\providecommand{\title}[1]{}% Make sure, \title is available

\providecommand{\thetitle}{Default Title}%


\newenvironment{environmentexample}{%
  \renewcommand{\title}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thetitle}{##1}%
  }
  This is the \thetitle.% too early
}{}



\newenvironment{otherenvironmentexample}[1][]{%
  \notblank{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\thetitle}{#1}%
  }{}
  This is the \thetitle.%
}{}


\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{environmentexample}
  \title{A title text}

  This is the title of the other environment: \thetitle
 \end{environmentexample}


\begin{otherenvironmentexample}
Something inside
\end{otherenvironmentexample}


\begin{otherenvironmentexample}[Let's change the title]
Something inside again!
\end{otherenvironmentexample}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In total, I recommend a key-value syntax here, depending on the amount of 'parameters' or properties, that should be set this way!

Comment: You forgot to remove the comment `% too early` from the definition of the environment with an optional argument: it’s misleading.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Yes, you're right! Thanks, I have removed the comment.